# play video from a certain position

Tags: php, html5-video

I'm trying to make a fake live video stream with HTML5 + PHP.

from my php, I have something like below.

```
$file = fopen("filename.mp4","rb");
fseek($file, 1000);

while(!feof($file) {
fread($file, 1024);
flush();
}
```

this code outputs correct data. The problem is that HTML5 video tag doesn't like partial content. I think it's because video tag only accept a complete mp4 format.

I've tried to set "**HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content**", but it didn't work either.

Is there a way to make html5 video tag to play a partial mp4 content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server will probably already do this work for you if you use Media Fragments. You can specify a URL with a start time and end time, and your browser will figure out what range of partial content to request from the server.

For example, if you want to watch a video starting at 10 seconds and going to 20 seconds, set the src url to:

http://foo.com/video.ogg#t=10,20

MDN describes the syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range), and if you're interested there's a more [technical slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/troncy/implementing-the-media-fragments-uri-specification).